# nouveau driver fills /var/log/kern.log and syslog

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, xorg, nouveau

After letting my desktop locked for 10 days, I found it frozen, with root filesystem 100% full.
Apparently, `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/syslog` have received more than 60'000 times per second the following line :

```
Jan  3 07:35:56 hostname kernel: [1091871.858753] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 04000000 [ACQUIRE] ch 2 [007f9a3000 Xorg[2915]] subc 0 mthd 001c data 00001004
```

This is with:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- linux-image-generic: 4.4.0
- xserver-xorg-video-nouveau: 1:1.0.12

What can we do with it?

Comment: I'd think stopping the excessive logging might be an idea, was that the only problem?

Comment: Yes, that's the only thing I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

That version of the `nouveau` driver seems to be buggy with my graphic card when the Desktop is in power saving (or at least with the screensaver).
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1474538

- One workaround can be to switch to nvidia driver : http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux
- An other possibility is to stay with nouveau driver, but use the latest version available through the installation of the "LTS Enablement Stack" : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus

That second option worked for me, so all I did was :

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

and reboot on the latest kernel & newer nouveau driver.

- linux-image-generic: 4.10.0
- xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-16.04 : 1.0.14